# Multiple rows merged into one row needs dupes removed

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

My query:

```
WITH RNs AS
(
    SELECT 
        NumID,
        LocID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NumID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM
        dbo.NUMLOC 
)
INSERT INTO TEMPCUSTNUMLOC (NumID, LocID1, LocID2, LocID3, LocID4, LocID5, LocID6, LocID7, LocID8, LocID9, LocID10, LocID11, LocID12, LocID13, LocID14, LocID15, LocID16, LocID17, LocID18)
    SELECT 
        NumID,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN LocID END) AS LocID1,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN LocID END) AS LocID2,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN LocID END) AS LocID3,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 4 THEN LocID END) AS LocID4,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 5 THEN LocID END) AS LocID5,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 6 THEN LocID END) AS LocID6,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 7 THEN LocID END) AS LocID7,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 8 THEN LocID END) AS LocID8,  
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 9 THEN LocID END) AS LocID9,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 10 THEN LocID END) AS LocID10,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 11 THEN LocID END) AS LocID11,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 12 THEN LocID END) AS LocID12,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 13 THEN LocID END) AS LocID13,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 14 THEN LocID END) AS LocID14,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 15 THEN LocID END) AS LocID15,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 16 THEN LocID END) AS LocID16,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 17 THEN LocID END) AS LocID17,
        MAX(CASE RN WHEN 18 THEN LocID END) AS LocID18
    FROM RNs R
GROUP BY NumID
```

Produces rows like this:

| NumID | LocID1 | LocID2 | LocID3 | LocID4 | LocID5 | LocID6 | LocID7 | LocID8 | LocID9 | LocID10 | LocID11 | LocID12 | LocID13 | LocID14 | LocID15 | LocID16 | LocID17 | LocID18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4515 | ABAB | ABBB | ABCB | ABDB | ABEB | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 8757 | ABAB | ABAB | ABAB | ABDB | ABEB | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2474 | ABAB | ABBB | ABCB | ABDB | ABEB | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

What I would like to see is that no NumID (8757 in this example) with a duplicate LocID***n***

| NumID | LocID1 | LocID2 | LocID3 | LocID4 | LocID5 | LocID6 | LocID7 | LocID8 | LocID9 | LocID10 | LocID11 | LocID12 | LocID13 | LocID14 | LocID15 | LocID16 | LocID17 | LocID18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4515 | ABAB | ABBB | ABCB | ABDB | ABEB | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 8757 | ABAB | ABDB | ABEB | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2474 | ABAB | ABBB | ABCB | ABDB | ABEB | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Sample Data from NUMLOC:

| NumID | LocID |
| --- | --- |
| 2474 | ABAB |
| 2474 | ABBB |
| 2474 | ABCB |
| 2474 | ABDB |
| 2474 | ABEB |
| 4515 | ABAB |
| 4515 | ABBB |
| 4515 | ABCB |
| 4515 | ABDB |
| 4515 | ABEB |
| 8757 | ABAB |
| 8757 | ABAB |
| 8757 | ABAB |
| 8757 | ABDB |
| 8757 | ABEB |

Comment: Can you include sample data for the NUMLOC table.

Comment: You can remove duplicates by using DISTINCT before you apply the row numbering. That seems a highly suspicious need but it's your data. And `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` is logical nonsense - run that query many times and you can see any particular LocID value in any of the 18 columns.

Comment: @SMor - Using  DISTINCT on NumID won't give me unique LocID. I think im going to have to create a table for this.

Comment: You can use `dense_rank() over (partition by NumID order by LocID)` rather than `row_number()`. That should be the equivalent of de-duping as a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is creating a temp table with unique values using distinct, as recommended by @smor.

After this query works great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).